# Why do I have to declare the list inside the loop?

Tags: html, python-3.x, list, tags

I just wrote the code below and it wasn't working like it's supposed to at first because I declared the list (`ltag`) outside the loop. I just wanna know what the difference is and why it didn't work in the first case.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter the URL mboy :')
pos= input("Enter position: ")
n= int(pos) - 1
count = input("Enter count: ")
c= int(count) +1

times = 0
while times < c :
    ltag = list()
    print('Retrieving: ', url)
    html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tags = soup('a')

    for i in range (c):
        for tag in tags:
            ltag.append(tag)
    url = ltag[n].get('href', None)
    times = times + 1
```

Comment: From a quick scan of the code, there doesn't seem to be a reason why the list ltag would need to be declared within the while loop to work.  Where it is declared prior to the while or after, it would still be in scope.  What error were you encountering when ltag is declared outside of the loop?

Comment: When it was outside the loop, I got the same url 5 times as the output but when it's inside I get different ones (just as I'm supposed to), so I guess when it was outside it wasn't updating or sth?

Comment: okay, that makes sense, when the loop is outside the while loop, the variable is declared once and each pass through the while loop, updates the list, so 5 passes through the while loop, results in 5 entries in the list.  With the list defined within the while loop, the scope of the list is the single pass through the loop, so you only get one entry in the list.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you very much!!